# I wish I had a new car

Tags: sentence-meaning, subjunctives

> "I wish I had a new car."

Does this mean I wish I had a new car but my current car is old? 
Is it an impossible wish or not?

Comment: Try a bilingual dictionary with your language.

Answer (score 1):

It might be either possible or impossible: you can't tell from the words.

Note that *a new car* is ambiguous: it might mean a brand-new car, or a second-hand car that you have just acquired.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I thought, but useful to have confirmation!